# How to search for a specific text and echo next characters of that specific text?

Tags: html, linux, bash, command-line

I have a project requirement where next characters of a text need to be printed after searching a specific text.

To understand better, here is an example.

I have an `index.html` file and would like to print a specific text after searching the text.

Question : I have text `<b>WELCOME</b>` in `index.html`. Now i want to search for `<b>`, print text `WELCOME` until `</b>`.

```
bash# cat index.html | grep "" ??
```

Please help me to print this content using a shell command or shell script in Linux.

Comment: I don't understand, do you want to strip the html tags to display only "WELCOME" ?

Comment: yes... But i want to print this from command line in *nix environment. can you help me ?

Comment: What are the conditions ? This is quite vague.
Is there some others `<b>` tags inside the html ? And what is your final need ? I  mean what are you trying to do with the output ?

Comment: yes it can have. But may be i want major tags like <title> / <header>, <footer> <h1> & <a> tags.

Comment: My questions are still not answered... Add details if you need help, we are not psychics.

Comment: Sorry for trouble, let me explain  : I need to write a script which needs to fetch basic info from a website and send e-mail. This is a daily job which needs to be done by our colleagues to check if any data is changing. Please help me ?

Comment: To help you, **I need to understand your needs** ! What does mean _i want to search for <b>_ ? If there's many `<b>`, what is the matching condition ? Or maybe you want to "grep" _WELCOME_ directly and strip tags ?

Comment: Ok ... lets ignore <b> tag ,  i want to search for <title> tag, since it is unique we can find it. Now I want to print the content inside <title> tag. (<title> $content </title> where $content = can be changable depending on website. )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Example to print the title of the current page in a quick & dirty way :

```
wget -q -O - 'http://tinyurl.com/9n6wayk' |
    sed -n '/<title>/{s:<title>\(.*\)</title>:\1:;p;q;}'
```

The sed command detailled :

- the `-n` option is there to display only the matching line
- the `//` part at the beginning is like a `grep` : we work with the matching line
- the `{}` is there to enclose the commands
- the `s:::` is a substitution (the delimiter can be any character, the default one is `/`)
- the `\(.*\)` is making a capture
- the \1 is the captured string
- `p` is there to print the modified string
- `q` is there to quit just after matching the line

A cleaner approach is to use [Xpath](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xpath) in a 3rd generation language like Python, Ruby or Perl.

A simple way to use Xpath in shell on the current stackoverflow page :

```
xmllint 2>/dev/null --html \
    --xpath '/html/head/title/text()' \
    http://tinyurl.com/9n6wayk
```

`xmllint` is a part of [libxml](http://www.xmlsoft.org/)

Comment: Using your approach, i have tried same command in ubuntu,  But it is printing only "<title>" .  Here is the command i tried ., curl -sq 'http://www.sap.com/index.epx' | fgrep '<title>' | sed 's:<title>\(.*\)<\/title>:\1:' , Result is just <title> .. :-(

Comment: See my edited post, I've found a better command line. Have you tried xmllint ?

Comment: If you think that the answer is useful, you can 'upvote' it. You can 'accept' the reply too by clicking the `checkmark` (will be green), this way, people searching stackoverflow website will know that the question is well answered. That's how stackoverflow works.

Comment: Thanks for update. I haven't tried xmllint. But anyways, i wil confirm.

Answer (score 0):

You could use sed for that:

```
sed -n -e 's/.*<b>\([^<]*\)<\/b>.*/\1/p' index.html
```

The "-n" flag tells sed to only print lines you tell it to.

The "s" command will replace a string that matches the regular expression with another string. I'll try to explain the regular expression (regex):

1. `.*` matches a sequence of characters
2. `<b>` matches the respective string
3. `\([^<]*\)` is a little more complex. For starters, the parenthesis prefixed with backslashes tells sed to store what it matches into an auxiliary variable. The `[^<]` matches any character except the `<` character, and the asterisk that follows tells that it should match a sequence of it (ie. a sequence of characters that aren't `<`).
4. `<\/b>` matches the `</b>` string, but we must escape the slash character with a backslash to not confuse sed into thinking it is the end of the regex.
5. `.*` matches another sequence of characters

After the regex, a string telling sed what to use as a replacement follows. In this case, it is simply `\1` which tells sed to print the first capture group (ie. in out case, everything that part 3 above matched, which means everything between `<b>` and `</b>`).

Finally after the last slash, we tell sed to print the replaced line with the "p" character. If a line doesn't match the regex, it won't be printed because we used the "-n" flag above.

Hope this helps =)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. I'm able to execute command. But there is no output. I have tried for <title> tag from index.html . sed -n -e 's/.*<title>\([^<]*\)<\/title>.*/\1/p' index.epx , But i dont get anything :-(

Comment: Is the title text case insensitive? Because if <Title> or <TITLE> appears it probably won't work. But also, I'm not sure if it was comment formatting (you can use backticks to show code), but in your comment the backslashes before the parenthesis are missing. You must use them, otherwise sed will try to match parenthesis characters in the input. Another problem could be if the tag is split between lines. In that case the commands are a little more complex. If it still doesn't work, or if you need anything else, feel free to ask =)